# Modify normal TCN to seq2seq TCN for binary classification

Tags: neural-networks, classification, conv-neural-network, audio

I'm working in PyTorch and I would like to use a Temporal Convolutional Neural Network (TCN) to perform binary classification for each timestep of an input sequence, therefore a Sequence-to-Sequence (Seq2Seq) TCN.

I'm considering the TCN PyTorch implementation defined [here](https://github.com/locuslab/TCN/blob/master/TCN/tcn.py) and [here](https://github.com/locuslab/TCN/blob/master/TCN/mnist_pixel/model.py) which is used [in this MNIST example](https://github.com/locuslab/TCN/blob/master/TCN/mnist_pixel/pmnist_test.py) to perform a multiclass classification, with 10 classes, since the MNIST dataset contains 10 digits (0-9).
Each image of the MNIST dataset is 28 x 28, therefore.
A tensor of shape `(B, 1, 28, 28)`, where B is the batch size, is reshaped as `(B, 1, 784)` and it is forwarded as input to the network, which produces an output of shape `(B, 10)` since there are 10 classes.

In my case, I extracted 40 MFCC (acoustic features) for every timestep of an audio input.
In order to pass a batch of tensors (each one containing 40 MFCC for 1500 timesteps) to the network, I reshaped a tensor of shape `(B, 1, 1500, 40)` to a tensor of shape `(B, 1, 60000)`.

Since I'm interested in binary classification, I set `n_classes` equal to 1 (instead of 10, as in the example) and I replaced softmax in [this line](https://github.com/locuslab/TCN/blob/master/TCN/mnist_pixel/model.py#L16) with `return F.sigmoid(o)`, and I obtain an output of shape `(B, 1)`.

Since I would like a prediction for each of the 1500 timesteps, I would like an output of shape `(B, 1500)`.

How should I modify the TCN implementation to achieve a TCN Sequence-to-Sequence (TCN Seq2Seq)?

Comment: I would expect the input to have to be of shape (B, 1500, 40)